# Using python matplotlib on i3 window manager

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have Manjaro 64 bit with i3 window manager (community release). I have a simple Python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    y = [n**2 for n in range(-1000,1000)]
    x = [n for n in range(-1000,1000)]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which should display `x^2` on my screen. The program runs for a second, then it stops, and no figure is shown on the screen. I tried uninstalling matplotlib (installed by pip) and installing in by hand, or through `pacman` (then it spams messages about some `.py` files, that they already exist, and: `Error occured. No packages were updated`), but no change. How can I make this work?

Comment: You could run it from the terminal and tell us if it shows you an error message.

Comment: Actually I found out what is wrong.`matplotlib.use()` can specify which GUI lib we would like to use. Just switched from something called `agg` to `TkAgg` as it is default on my Windows OS